# Advantages of extension methods vs uniform function call syntax (UFCS)?

Tags: syntax, language-design

Extension methods and Uniform Function Call Syntax (UFCS) are two different ways of letting you write a method call like `foo.bar()` without `bar` being a method originally defined on `foo`.

Extension methods are methods added to a type outside of the type's original definition. They let you add a `.sum()` method on a type such as `List` even if you didn't define `List` yourself. This `.sum()` extension method, however, is not a free function that can be passed around. It must be called on a `List` object. C#, Kotlin, and many other languages have extension methods.

UFCS is very similar, except there's no special extension methods that are treated differently. You can take a free function that would normally be called like `foo(bar, baz)` and instead call it like `bar.foo(baz)`. Ideally, this would also work the other way: a method `.foo()` on some object `bar` should be able to be called as `foo(bar)` too (although D, a language with UFCS, doesn't fully support this).

My question is this: what are the advantages and disadvantages of extension methods and uniform function call syntax? What trade-offs are made when choosing one over the other, and in what circumstance would you prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 7):

The most important difference is that extension methods do not require that the language has overloading, while UFCS is built on top of overloading.

Comment: This allowed Kotlin to use them to great effect to build their own collections library on top of Java collections classes that they cannot add methods to.

Comment: This makes it sound as if UFCS could not be implemented in a dynamically typed language, but I really can't see a reason for that. It would just require some rules for when to treat `bar.foo` as an attribute lookup and when to treat it as a sugared call to `foo`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel consider the function `foo(bar, baz)`, then we must at least assume that this function is different from `foo(abc, baz)` i.e. there is a concept of overloading or the use is very limited as we cannot reuse any function name once it is defined.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Overloading is a dynamically-typed language is just called "multimethods". Julia designs its entire semantics around multimethods, and it works quite well in practice.

Answer (score 4):

## New conformances

In languages with nominal rather than structural typing, UFCS doesn't let you add a new protocol conformance to an existing type, but extensions can, e.g. (Swift):

```
protocol MyNumericThing {
  func add(_ other: Self) -> Self
}

extension Int: MyNumericThing {
  func add(_ other: Int) -> Int { self + other }
}
```

Of course, this comes with the danger of *retroactive conformances*, which you can read more about [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/retroactive-conformances-vs-swift-in-the-os/14393).

Answer (score 3):

### Freedom in calling syntax

Without UFCS, you have to call a procedure/method with the syntax that the author wanted you to use. With UFCS, you can freely decide which syntax works better in your context.